# open pdf in the phonegap(ios) ipad application

Tags: ios5, phonegap-plugins

I am cross platform ipad Application developer.I am trying to open a pdf file in my application with text search option. Is there any possibility to load the pdf file within the application?    Is phonegap plugin needed for that? Can i usd CGScanner to search the text in the pdf?

Comment: How to open pdf file in ios using phonegap? please give idea.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it'd be something similar to this method [here](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2012/01/24/embed-a-youtube-video-iframe-in-phonegap-app/).  Though that's not going to give you search necessarily.